# How to delete a single pygame drawing from the screen?

Tags: python, pygame, draw

When the big circle touches the little circles I want the little circle that it touched to disappear from the screen. However, I can't figure out how exactly you delete an individual drawing in pygame. How do I fix this issue? does pygame have this feature built-in?

```
from pygame import *
import random as rd
import math as m

init()
screen = display.set_mode((800, 600))

p_1_x = 200
p_1_y = 200
p_1_change_x = 0
p_1_change_y = 0

def p_1(x, y):
    player_1 = draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 0), (x, y), 15)

def pick_up(x, y, xx, yy):
    distance = m.sqrt(m.pow(xx - x, 2) + m.pow(yy - y, 2))
    if distance < 19:
        # I think the code to delete should go here
        pass

dots = []
locations = []

for i in range(5):
    x = rd.randint(100, 700)
    y = rd.randint(100, 500)
    locations.append((x, y))

while True:
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    for events in event.get():
        if events.type == QUIT:
            quit()
        if events.type == KEYDOWN:
            if events.key == K_RIGHT:
                p_1_change_x = 1
            if events.key == K_LEFT:
                p_1_change_x = -1
            if events.key == K_UP:
                p_1_change_y += 1
            if events.key == K_DOWN:
                p_1_change_y -= 1

        if events.type == KEYUP:
            if events.key == K_RIGHT or K_LEFT or K_UP or K_DOWN:
                p_1_change_x = 0
                p_1_change_y = 0

    p_1_x += p_1_change_x
    p_1_y -= p_1_change_y
    for i, locate in enumerate(locations):
        dot = draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 0), locate, 5)
        dots.append(dot)
        for l in enumerate(locate):
            pick_up(p_1_x, p_1_y, locate[0], locate[1])

    p_1(p_1_x, p_1_y)
    display.update()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code was so messy and hard to maintain, first I made 2 classes for Balls & Dots.
I detect collision by `pygame.Rect.colliderect`, first I make 2 rectangle then I check the collision like this:

```
def pick_up(ball, dot):
    ball_rect = Rect( ball.x - ball.SIZE , ball.y - ball.SIZE , ball.SIZE*2, ball.SIZE*2)
    dot_rect = Rect( dot.x - dot.SIZE , dot.y - dot.SIZE , dot.SIZE*2, dot.SIZE*2)
    if ball_rect.colliderect(dot_rect): 
        return True
    return False
```

If collision detects I remove it from dots array in the `while` loop:

```
for dot in dots:
    if pick_up(ball, dot): # if dot in range ball
            dots.remove(dot)
    dot.draw()
```

Here is the whole source:

```
from pygame import *
import random as rd

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
NUMBER_OF_DOTS = 5

class Ball():
    SIZE = 15
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        
    def draw(self):
        draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y), Ball.SIZE)
    def move(self, vx, vy):
        self.x += vx
        self.y += vy

class Dot():
    SIZE = 5    
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        
    def draw(self):
        draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y), Dot.SIZE)


def pick_up(ball, dot):
    ball_rect = Rect( ball.x - ball.SIZE , ball.y - ball.SIZE , ball.SIZE*2, ball.SIZE*2)
    dot_rect = Rect( dot.x - dot.SIZE , dot.y - dot.SIZE , dot.SIZE*2, dot.SIZE*2)
    if ball_rect.colliderect(dot_rect): 
        return True
    return False



init()
screen = display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

dots = []
ball = Ball(200,200)

# generate dots
for i in range(NUMBER_OF_DOTS):
    x = rd.randint(100, 700)
    y = rd.randint(100, 500)
    dots.append(Dot(x,y))

# the main game loop
while True:
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    keys=key.get_pressed()

    for events in event.get():
        keys=key.get_pressed()
        if events.type == QUIT:
            quit()

    if keys[K_RIGHT]:
        ball.move(+1,0)
    if keys[K_LEFT]:
        ball.move(-1,0)
    if keys[K_UP]:
        ball.move(0,-1)
    if keys[K_DOWN]:
        ball.move(0,+1)

    for dot in dots:
        dot.draw()
        
        if pick_up(ball, dot):
                dots.remove(dot)

    ball.draw()
    display.update()
    time.delay(1) # Speed down
```

### Update1:

PyGame Rectangle Collision
http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect

### Update2:

I make a repo in the github and did some changes,
Dots are colorful, new dot gets random color and the ball gets bigger whenever eats a dot.
[image: shot]

https://github.com/peymanmajidi/Ball-And-Dots-Game__Pygame

Answer (score 3):

The code should delete it from the `locations` list so that it's not re-drawn in the future.  You clear the screen each frame, so clearing + not-redrawing is "deleting".

Say you modified `pick_up()` to simply return True or False:

```
def pick_up(x, y, xx, yy):
    result = False
    distance = m.sqrt(m.pow(xx - x, 2) + m.pow(yy - y, 2))
    if distance < 19:
        result = True              # It was picked
    return result
```

Then as you iterate through the `locations` list drawing & checking for being picked, save the index of the picked circles, then remove them from the `locations` in a second step.  Using the 2-step form means you don't have to worry about accidentally skipping items if you delete from the list as you iterate over it.

```
p_1_x += p_1_change_x
p_1_y -= p_1_change_y
picked_up = []                           # empty list to hold "picked" items
for i, locate in enumerate(locations):
    dot = draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 0), locate, 5)
    dots.append(dot)
    for l in enumerate(locate):
        if ( pick_up(p_1_x, p_1_y, locate[0], locate[1]) ):
            picked_up.append( i )        # save the index of anything "picked"

# remove any picked-up circles from the list
for index in sorted( picked_up, reverse=True ):   # start with the highest index first
    print( "Removing circle from location[%d]" % ( index ) )  # DEBUG
    del( locations[ index ] )
```

Comment: Why does it sometimes say that the index is out of range?

Comment: @mr.bug - Ah, maybe the `sorted()` is not working as I imagined?  It should be deleting the largest element first, so they get removed from the "far end" of the list.  Ah, or maybe it's getting multiple collisions at the end of the list?  You could add a `print()` to see the index of what's being removed.